# Golang Embed folder containing another exe

Tags: go

I have following project structure.

Project 1 - golang project binary. and main project.

[image]

I want to embed project1 directory in main project and call the exe present in that project.

```
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

//go:embed Project1
var contentofproject1 embed.FS

func main() {

    entries, err := contentofproject1.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("failed reading directory: %s", err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(entries); i++ {
        fmt.Println(entries[i].Name())
        fmt.Println(entries[i].IsDir())
    }

    out, err := exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "Project1\\main.exe").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("The date is %s\n", out)

}
```

But this does not work when I created binary and move to some other location.

How can I access the exe embedded in a directory inside go binary?
can I embed a directory containing .net exe and supporting dll and execute it using exec.Command(???)

Comment: You cannot cmd exec an embeded file. You have to copy it onto disk and cmd exe it there (with cmd or directly. contentofproject1 lets you access what is embeded but it doesnt provide any magic.

Comment: Embedded files are a Go construct, launching an executable is an OS construct. The OS cannot execute a file embedded in a Go program. You have to write it to disk and then run it.